# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity with scoped roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity

I struggle a bit to understand how to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` to create scoped roles.

## Example

I have a `User` that can manage `Cars`. When I give one user the `Role` "Admin" I don't want him to be admin of all `Cars`.

## Goal

I want to have an additional `CarRole` that that is linked to `User` and(!) `Car`.

## Question

How can I extend the Identity framework to get this to work?
I don't found any starting point inside the documentation.
Also, do I need to check the scoped role then from inside the controller action and not by attribute?
Or am I completely wrong and used specific `Claims` on `Roles` to get this behavior working?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but while setting the authentication, we can set the claims for role and car separately and do check both using customattribute?

Comment: You might want to use the Active Directory Users and Computers Windows GUI to wrap your head around Identities.  You should be able to create multiple Roles with different levels of permissions.